# How to linearize this nonlinear system?

Tags: nonlinear-system, jacobian, linearization

Take a look at this nonlinear system
$$
\dddot{x} +4\ddot{x}+24|\dot{x}| + 5\cos(x)|\dot{x}| + 50x = u
$$
The objective is to linearize the system about the equilibrium point. First, we compute the equilibrium point but we need first to convert the third degree of ODE to first order ODE. 
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 &= x \implies \dot{x}_1 = x_2 \implies f_1(\boldsymbol{x},u) \\
x_2 &= \dot{x} \implies \dot{x}_2 = x_3 \implies f_2(\boldsymbol{x},u) \\
x_3 &= \ddot{x} \implies \dot{x}_3 = \dddot{x} \implies f_3(\boldsymbol{x},u) \\
\end{align}
$$
where 
$$
\dddot{x} = u - 4x_3-24|x_2| - 5\cos(x_1)|x_2| - 50x_1
$$
The new form of the system is 
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
f_1(\boldsymbol{x},u) \\ f_2(\boldsymbol{x},u) \\ f_3(\boldsymbol{x},u)
\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_2 \\ x_3 \\ u - 4x_3-24|x_2| - 5\cos(x_1)|x_2| - 50x_1
\end{bmatrix} \\
\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}&=f(\boldsymbol{x},u) 
\end{align}
$$
The new form is indeed a first order system. Assume $u=0$. Now, we compute the equilibrium point(s) which can be obtained as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}&=f(\boldsymbol{x}_e,u_e) = 0  \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
The only equilibrium point for Eq.(1) is $(\boldsymbol{x}_e,u_e)=(\boldsymbol{0},0)$ or $x_1=0,x_2=0,x_3=0,u=0$. Now we compute the **Jacobain** matrix as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
A = \frac{\partial f(\boldsymbol{x},u)}{\boldsymbol{x}} \Big|_{\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{x}_e} 
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1(\boldsymbol{x},u)}{x_1} &
\frac{\partial f_1(\boldsymbol{x},u)}{x_2} &
\frac{\partial f_1(\boldsymbol{x},u)}{x_3} \\
\frac{\partial f_2(\boldsymbol{x},u)}{x_1} &
\frac{\partial f_2(\boldsymbol{x},u)}{x_2} &
\frac{\partial f_2(\boldsymbol{x},u)}{x_3} \\
\frac{\partial f_3(\boldsymbol{x},u)}{x_1} &
\frac{\partial f_3(\boldsymbol{x},u)}{x_2} &
\frac{\partial f_3(\boldsymbol{x},u)}{x_3} 
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
-50 &
\frac{24x_2+5\cos(x_1)x_2}{|x_2|} &
-4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Clearly $\frac{24x_2+5\cos(x_1)x_2}{|x_2|}$ is undefined at the equilibrium point. How to proceed from this point?

Comment: Why do you care if it is defined at the equilibrium point. Usually this would be used to analyze the behavior *near* equilibrium.

Comment: @Spencer probably to analyze the stability first and design a controller subsequently if the system is stable.

Comment: And in which of those circumstances do you need to evaluate $A$ *at* the equilibrium point?

Comment: @Spencer to compute the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. It is different than what I would do myself in analyzing the behavior of a system. I would only care about the behavior near equilibrium, not necessarily at it.

Comment: @Spencer if one of the eigenvalues is zero basically linearization method doesn't tell us about the stability, at this case we need to utilize nonlinear control approaches. I've noticed changing the undefined parameter with -1000, the system is indeed stable and with positive values the system is unstable which I don't bother to compute the Jacobain.

Comment: @CroCo Do you have to do it by linearizing (as in a problem that ask you explicitly to linearize)? Because it doesn't seems that it work, but the system is clearly controllable(locally and globally) and feedback stabilizable.

Comment: @themaker yes. I need to design a linear controller.

Comment: As far as I see, the system is not linearizable due to the $|\cdot|$ function. However, if the goal is to design a linear controller, then I guess that $u=-44 x_2$ will do the job.